# With phpcs for VSCode, how can I change the font color of an error based on the ruleset it violated?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, standards, phpcs

I am using [PHP Code Sniffer (phpcs) for VSCode](https://github.com/ikappas/vscode-phpcs).  It contains a set of PHP coding rules, and when it detects a violation of one of these rules, it displays those errors in VSCode.  These errors are separate to the PHP coding errors detected and displayed by VSCode<sup>1</sup>.  When phpcs detects what it considers an error, it displays that error in red colored font--the exact same color that VSCode uses to display *its* errors ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgVjc.jpg)).  Is there any way to style either of those errors in a different color (or different font), so I can quickly distinguish between the two?

The reason I ask is because the 'errors' reported by phpcs are non-critical, while the 'errors' reported by VSCode can sometimes be critical errors (i.e. something that will result in a PHP fatal error). It would be nice to see a distinction between the two.

As an alternative, if I could classify all phpcs 'errors' as 'warnings' instead, that would be suitable for me.  To me, most (all?) issues reported by phpcs would fall under the 'warning' category, rather than the 'error' category.

I found [this old ticket](https://github.com/ikappas/vscode-phpcs/issues/36) on the phpcs GitHub page.  It is a few years old, but says it is not possible to do what I want.  I just thought I'd ask here if anyone knew of a recent solution or workaround.

---

<sup>1</sup> This functionality is enabled in VSCode, out of the box.